# DialogFlow doesn't recognize numbers two an four

Tags: dialogflow-es

Using the telephony integration in DialogFlow, when trying to capture an intent like (for example)

> I'm looking for the number six

Where `six` is defined as `@sys.cardinal` or `@sys.number`
I would get it to recognize any single digit except 2 & 4.
For those the text would almost consistently read as "to" & "for" respectively.
This would happen both on the phone, and when testing on the Dialogflow console, pressing the little microphone icon and recording the input.

Why is it missing these numbers when it knows I'm expecting a number in that position?
What can I do to give it better hints?

Answer (score 1):

If the exact phrase the user speaks is "I'm looking for the number two" I believe the agent will detect is as a number based on the context of the phrase.

If they just say "two" it may detect as "to" instead.

Will users only be able to provide a single digit here? If so, perhaps you can create an example for every number (given there are only 10 digits that wouldn't be too onerous).

However, if you're expecting the user to provide a string of numbers perhaps try a different data type for the parameter.  The number-sequence type might be more suitable.